# Make a loop with procedures that involve certain files from a list?

Tags: python, loops

I have the following list:

`grouped_shapefiles` that has these directories for the files:(pairs of pst and dbound) in each folder.

```
[['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20194\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20194\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20042\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20042\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20161\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20161\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20029\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20029\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20008\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20008\\PST\\PST.shp']]
```

I want to make a for loop that performs this piece of code in the corresponding files for each `pst` and `dbound` pair in every folder (`20194,20042,20161`,etc...) that the list contains.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas
#pst = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder1\PST')#this is not needed in the final because it takes the path by it self
#dbound = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder1\DBOUND')#same here
dbound.reset_index(inplace=True)
wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst, dbound, how="inner", op='within')#each dbound and pst from every folder
wdp['DEC_ID']=wdp['index']
```

I just want to know how to make the for loop that will perform what the code has in the files that should. I have tried with for loops and using the position in brackets but it didn't do what it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly, are you trying to iterate through the items in list in pairs? If so it is pretty straight forward:

```
for i in grouped_shapefiles:
    pst = gpd.read_file(i[0])
    dbound = gpd.read_file(i[1])
    if i[0].split("\\")[-3] == i[1].split("\\")[-3]:
        dbound.reset_index(inplace=True)
        wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst, dbound, how="inner", op='within')
        wdp['DEC_ID'] = wdp['index']
    else:
        print ("Folder pairs mismatch")
```

Edited as per my understanding

Comment: The last script I've written should be applied in the for loop using the pairs that you just created.If you can make it work would be nice.

Comment: Edited as above

Comment: And how to export it if the code for export is:  `o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\yyyyyh'` `wdp.to_file(o) ` so it can attach to each output file title its unique folder name so the user can know from which folder originate? example: wdp_20194,etc

Comment: Add `folder=i[0].split("\\")[-3]` and `o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\wdp_'+folder`

Comment: Thank you very much, really great.